# Android ToggleButton crash (resource NullPointerException)

Tags: android, resources, togglebutton

I'm new to android and i've just been getting myself familiar with it and i've stumbled on this problem with fetching resources. I've added a toggle button on to the main layout but when i access the resource and then try to change text with `button.setText()` the app crashes.

Here is the relevant code listing:

main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.games.tiktakboom.GameView
      android:id="@+id/game"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    <ToggleButton android:layout_width="120px" android:id="@+id/toggleButton1" android:layout_height="120px" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:background="@drawable/bomb"></ToggleButton>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class TikTakBoom extends Activity {
    ...
    public ToggleButton startButton;
    ...

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // turn off the window's title bar
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        // tell system to use the layout defined in our XML file
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // get handles to the LunarView from XML, and its LunarThread
        mGameView = (GameView) findViewById(R.id.game);
        mGameThread = mGameView.getThread();

        // set up a new game
        mGameThread.setState(GameThread.STATE_READY);
        Log.w(this.getClass().getName(), "SIS is null");

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(mGameThread, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);

        startButton = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
        startButton.setText("test");
    }

...
```

Btw, this is a modified template i got on some forum or something, that's why the weird comments.

The app crashes as soon as i try to fetch te resource with `findViewById`. If i put this button in another class the app crashes on `setText()`. I have no idea why it doesn't fetch the resource correctly, a problem with the layout possibly?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks. Cheers.

Val

FIRST PART SOLVED: CLEAN PROJECT AND RESTART ECLIPSE. (lol)

EDIT (still open for possible solutions):
It seems that restarting Eclipse solved the problem (clean project and restarting didn't work before..), go figure.

But my question is sort of a follow up, if i fetch the button resource from another class it still crashes on `setText()` or any other atempt to modify the button's properties (as far as debugger says it's also supposed to be NullPointerException). I've read somewhere that a button resource is only valid if fetched inside Activity class, tho i didn't believe it at the time. Is there any truth to this or better yet, any reason for that?

The relevant code segment:

```
class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
class GameThread extends Thread implements SensorEventListener {
    ..
    ToggleButton startButton;
    ..
    public GameThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Context context,
            Handler handler) {
        // get handles to some important objects
        mSurfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        mHandler = handler;
        mContext = context;

        mBomb = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.bomb);

        startButton = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    }
    ..
    /* Callback invoked when the surface dimensions change. */
    public void setSurfaceSize(int width, int height) {
        // synchronized to make sure these all change atomically
        synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
            mCanvasWidth = width;
            mCanvasHeight = height;
        }

        mBomb = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBomb, (int)(mCanvasHeight/4), (int)(mCanvasHeight/4), true);

        startButton.setTextOn("test");
    }
    ..
```

I know, this code doesn't make much sense, should work tho.. Any ideas as to why the previous atempt to fetch the resource works and not in another class? Tnx.

EDIT:

Here is my logcat, sorry for the delay.

```
08-17 00:48:46.891: WARN/dalvikvm(30139): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400207d8)
```

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.games.tiktakboom/com.games.tiktakboom.TikTakBoom}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error
>   inflating class com.games.tiktakboom.GameView

```
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2669)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2685)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:126)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2038)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6:
>   Error inflating class com.games.tiktakboom.GameView

```
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:200)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
at com.games.tiktakboom.TikTakBoom.onCreate(TikTakBoom.java:100)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2633)
... 11 more
```

> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

```
at com.games.tiktakboom.GameView.<init>(GameView.java:354)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
... 21 more
```

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

```
at com.games.tiktakboom.GameView$GameThread.<init>(GameView.java:101)
... 25 more
```

> Force finishing activity com.games.tiktakboom/.TikTakBoom

As said, the log points to a NullPointerException (on the fetched resource). I can't make out the rest. Any help would be appreciated since i can't seem to be able to solve this problem. Thanks, cheers.

EDIT:
Perhaps a problem with contexts? The context is passed to the constructor when a new thread is constructed. Do i have to manually fetch resources from the passed context variable or something?

Comment: Have you attempted to clean your project. That fixes a lot of resource problems

Comment: Ok this is really weird, i DID try clean, that was my first thought AND i restarted eclipse, didn't work. Now i did the same and it works.. Tho it still doesn't work if i fetch the resource from another class, is there a particular reason why a button resource has to be fetched inside Activity class?.. Thank you for you help, i'll keep the thread open for now and edit my post.

Answer (score 1):

Instead, try:

```
startButton.setTextOn("test");
startButton.setTextOff("test");
```